# Django RestApi - Seperation between API and Webbackend

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my project I use the django-rest-framework to add a REST API to my Webpage.

Is it ok to run everything on the same django instance? 
Or is the separation of the Api and the Webbackend the better way to go?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no reason to separate regular backend and REST API into two instances. As you want them to use the same models and the same database backend. A good practice is to just add a new url prefix /api/ in your root urls.py

```
api_urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.api.urls')),
    ...
)


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^api/', include(api_urlpatterns, namespace='api')),
    ...
)
```

With a namespace for the api you can easily avoid collisions between API urls and your standard views. And it makes for easier to understand code too:

```
reverse('api:mymodel-list')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will mostly depend on your goals.

In most cases, it's ok to keep both on the same instance.

In some cases however you probably won't do that if the site / API settings differ. For example if you have lots of middleware that you only use for the site part and want a well tuned API for performances.

Keep in mind that having different instances for the site and API costs hosting and integration/devops/administration time.